# 'Scrambbled?' Pick the anagram

Tags: english, anagram

First time poster, puzzle is rather short:

> AEIOLN = KAOLINE
>
> OLT = JOLT
>
> AEILNTR = ???

Edit:
One more example to help guide your way to my hoped for pattern (answers from before this may break, but are all very good).

> CJK = JACK, JOCK

Edit 2:
Another example (last one, think about word games):

> AIFR = FAQIR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have established by now that the answer is ...

> ... an anagram of the given letters plus one additional letter. According to the OP, not all such answers are valid, though.

There is a hint in the title:

> "Scrambbled" is "scrambled" plus the letter "b", but it might also be "scrabbled" plus "m".

Let's follow this hint and ...

> ... determine the Scrabble scores for the example answers:
>
>  KAOLINE: 11
>  JOLT: 11
>  JACK: 17
>  JOCK: 17
>  FAQIR: 17
>
>  These scores are not the same for all answers, but they share a common property: They are all prime numbers.

The answer is therefore:

> **INTERVAL** with a Scrabble score of 11. (There's also "inflater" with the same score, but "interval" seems to be a more common word.)

Thanks, feelinferrety, for doing the legwork of finding the possible anagrams.

Answer (score 9):

AEIOLN = KAOLINE

OLT = JOLT

AEILNTR = ???

> INERTIAL
>  
>  There are many possibilities that can be made from adding a letter and unscrambling, but since you added 'k' in the first instance, then 'j', the next one you add 'i' and the only possibility is inertial.

Comment: Not quite what I was going for (how did I only pick JOLT and KAOLINE for the other two?)

Comment: @AdamMartin Edited to show a pattern.

Comment: Not the pattern I was looking for but +1!

Answer (score 4):

## AEILNTR

Since we are given only two solved cases, I can only speculate as to the *actual* rules and intended answer, so I'll list my own process of elimination below to offer a solution.

**RULE 1**

> Anagrams made possible with the addition of one extra letter:

Result:

> **`C :`** clarinet
> **`E :`** entailer
> **`F :`** inflater
> **`G :`** triangle tanglier relating integral altering alerting
> **`I :`** inertial
> **`M :`** tramline terminal
> **`N :`** internal
> **`O :`** relation oriental
> **`P :`** triplane
> **`S :`** retinals ratlines latrines entrails
> **`V :`** interval

**RULE 2**

> <strike>Anagram contains the vowels listed in the order listed.</strike> FAILED
>  The anagram begins with the additional letter.

Result:

> clarinet, entailer, inertial, oriental

**RULE 3**

> The additional letter does not repeat an existing letter.

Result:

> clarinet, oriental

**RULE 4**

> The additional letter is a consonant.
>  Bonus: Result is a noun.

Result and **ANSWER**:

> **CLARINET**

Comment: Nice thought process, but I'm going to add a little tidbit in the question to hint at my aimed pattern which no one has gotten yet which will break some of these (just FYI).  +1

Answer (score 2):

AEIOLN = KAOLINE

OLT = JOLT

AEILNTR = ???

> IALNITER
>  
>  
>  First letter might be in sequence 'k' in the first, then 'j', so the next one can be 'I'.
>  
>  
>   Then you have selected the first letter from the 2 words. 'A' in first and 'o' in the second.
>  
>  
>  Then you have gone to middle letter and then from left to right the letters are interchanged.

Answer (score 0):

> Clarinet, Interval... There are many words.  Do you want them all?

Comment: Nope, there are more words for the first two examples that aren't listed.